# How to make duplicate recordID's as one in Python

Tags: python, json, logging

I need a small fix in my code. When i ran below code I am getting duplicate record id's with the data. How could i make this duplicate record id's as one and print the data.

```
import base64
import json
import re
import gzip


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []
    equals = '='
    
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = json.loads(gzip.decompress(
            base64.b64decode(record['data'])))
        
        print(payload['logEvents'])
        
        for syslog_events in payload['logEvents']:

          if equals in syslog_events['message']:
              toJson = dict(item.split("=") for item in syslog_events['message'].split(","))
              value = list(toJson.keys())[0]
              toJson[value[-2:]] = toJson.pop(value)
              json_payload = json.dumps(toJson)

          else:
              json_payload = 'Process_Failed'

          output_record = {
              'recordId': record['recordId'],
              'result': 'Ok',
              'data': base64.b64encode(json_payload.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
            }

          output.append(output_record)

    print(json.dumps(output))

    return {'records': output}
```

Each recordID contains multiple logs and I am fetching all the logs as one data under one record ID. I got struck here to finish it.
**actual ouput: print(json.dumps(output))**

```
{
    "recordId": "123456",
    "result": "Ok",
    "data": "{"recordtime": "2023-05-17T13:59:28Z", "color": "red", "user": "rdsdb"}"
}, 
{
    "recordId": "123456",
    "result": "Ok",
    "data": "{"recordtime": "2023-05-17T13:59:28Z", "color": "blue", "name": "chiya"}"
}, 
{
    "recordId": "123456",
    "result": "Ok",
    "data": "{"recordtime": "2023-05-17T13:59:28Z", "sky": "red", "moon": "blue"}"
}, 
{
    "recordId": "7890",
    "result": "Ok",
    "data": "{"name": "rahy", "age": "25"}"
}, 
{
    "recordId": "7890",
    "result": "Ok",
    "data": "{"branch": "hdsf", "color": "blue", "area": "gully"}"
}
```

**Expected output: print(json.dumps(output))**

```
{
    "recordId": "123456",
    "result": "Ok",
    "data": "{"recordtime": "2023-05-17T13:59:28Z", "color": "red", "user": "rdsdb"}", "{"recordtime": "2023-05-17T13:59:28Z", "color": "blue", "name": "chiya"}", "{"recordtime": "2023-05-17T13:59:28Z", "sky": "red", "moon": "blue"}"
}, 
{
    "recordId": "7890",
    "result": "Ok",
    "data": "{"name": "rahy", "age": "25"}", "{"branch": "hdsf", "color": "blue", "area": "gully"}"
}
```

Since long time I am holding this item. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: At the moment `output` is a list you append into. It should be a dictionary with a key of recordId and you will append into the data element of the value of that key. Try that and if you are still struggling let us know and someone will post a solution